# Separating parenthesis using python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Given a string consisting of groups of matched parentheses and whitespace, Write a human friendly python program to split the string into groups of perfectly matched parentheses without any whitespace.

```
Input:  ( ()) ((()()())) (()) ()        Output: ['(())', '((()()()))', '(())', '()']
Input:  () (( ( )() ( )) ) ( ())        Output: ['()', '((()()()))', '(())']
```

```
def split_parentheses(input_string):
    result = []
    stack = []
    for char in input_string:
        if char == '(':
            stack.append(char)
        elif char == ')':
            if len(stack) > 0 and stack[-1] == '(':
                stack.pop()
                if len(stack) == 0:
                    result.append(''.join(stack))
                    stack = []  # clear stack for the next group
            else:
                return "Invalid input string: parentheses not perfectly matched."
    if len(stack) > 0:
        return "Invalid input string: parentheses not perfectly matched."
    return result

def wrap_with_parentheses(string):
    return f'({string})'

input_string = input("Enter a string of perfectly matched parentheses and whitespace: ")
result = split_parentheses(input_string)
result = list(map(wrap_with_parentheses, result))
print(result)
```

This doesn't display multiple groups of parenthesis with nesting like `((()()()))`

Comment: `if len(stack) == 0:` `''.join(stack)` Please tell us what your reasoning behind this is and why you think this should do anything. Hint: the following `stack = []` is idempotent.

Comment: Why the `python-2.7` tag?

Comment: The stack works, but is unneeded. Try to replace `stack = []` with `depth = 0` and every occurrence of `stack.append(char)` with `depth += 1` and every occurrence of `stack.pop()` with `depth -= 1`. And replace every `len(stack) > 0` by `depth > 0` and every `len(stack) == 0` by `depth == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

- In the inner `if` block, the stack is empty (it was tested to be empty), so `''.join(stack)` will always be an empty string, and clearing the stack is a useless operation, since it is already empty.
- Since you pop all `(` from the stack and the stack never receives any `)`, there is no way to reconstruct the final string from the stack. You need a separate variable to collect the parentheses. This could be a string variable.
- It makes no sense to wrap the results with another pair of parentheses as it just invents parentheses that have no relation with the input. So drop `wrap_with_parentheses`.

Other remark:

- As the stack only receives `(` characters, you don't actually need those characters (what else could it be?), but only the length. For that you can use a numeric variable, like `depth`. It would correspond to `len(stack)` without actually having the stack.

Here is a correction of your code:

```
def split_parentheses(input_string):
    result = []
    depth = 0  # Use this instead of a stack
    current = ""  # This variable will collect the string that will be a single entry in the result
    for char in input_string:
        if char in "()":
            current += char  # Collect all the parentheses
        if char == '(':
            depth += 1
        elif char == ')':
            depth -= 1
            if depth < 0:
                return "Invalid input string: parentheses not perfectly matched."
            if depth == 0:
                result.append(current)
                current = "" # clear string for the next group
    if depth:
        return "Invalid input string: parentheses not perfectly matched."
    return result


input_string = input("Enter a string of perfectly matched parentheses and whitespace: ")
result = split_parentheses(input_string)
print(result)
```

Comment: Regarding *"Since you pop all ( from the stack and the stack never receives any ), there is no way to reconstruct the final string from the stack. You need a separate variable to collect the parentheses. This could be a string variable."* Alternatively, you could just keep the index of the start of the substring, and then append `input_string[start:i]` to `result`.

Comment: Thannk you so much